# simultaneous operations on multiple files in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i have a list of id in a textfile = id1,id2,id3 etc

```
val IDList = sc.textFile("/home/.../IDList.csv").flatMap(line => line.split(","))
```

each id is associated to csv dataframe in a repo : 
"/home/data/" + idX  + "/*.csv"

for each id in the IDList o would like to read the data and processed it

i tried to do something like this without result :

```
val IDList = sc.textFile("/home/.../IDList.csv").flatMap(line => line.split(","))
    IDList.map(x => {
          val path =  "/home/data" + x + "/*.csv"
          val dataFrame = sparkSession.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load(path)
            .withColumn().filter()blablabla
          // save 
          dataFrame.repartition(1).write.format("csv").option("header","true").save("/home/g179887/Desktop/test")
        })
```

Thank's for help

Comment: Spark does not support nested RDDs/Dataframes/Datasets.

Comment: Well... how can i do what i want to do ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use scala `parallel collections` to store the id list & use `spark` to read the file contents. By this way, spark can read the contents 
 & operate multiple files simultaneously.

```
import scala.io.Source
val IDList = Source.fromFile("/home/.../IDList.csv").getLines.toList.par
```

the contents of `.map()` can stay the same.

Comment: Thank you, it works for my little example, i'll try to apply to my application